# Query taking more than 5 minutes to execute

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I've a query that runs in 2 identical environments: Production and QA. In QA server, it takes around 6 seconds and in production it takes 5 minutes or more!

Query is as follows:

```
    mysql> SELECT  s.id_shopper, 
      ( SELECT  count(*)
            FROM  shopper s2
            JOIN  orders o2 ON o2.id_shopper = s2.id_shopper
              AND  o2.order_status in ('V','X')
            WHERE  o2.id_shopper = s.id_shopper
      )as num_ordenes, s.upi,
        s.email, s.first_name, s.last_name1, s.last_name2, s.shtype,
        s.active, s.shtype, s.registered_on AS regdate, s.upi_type AS upi_type,
        s.gender, s.birthday, s.phtype1, s.phacode1, s.phone1,
        s.phtype2, s.phacode2, s.phone2, s.sellercode, s.mail_offers,
        c.name as pais, r.name as region, ct.name as ciudad, a.name as area,
        s.postcode, s.street, s.street_number,
        concat(r.name, " - ", a.name) as comuna_compra
    FROM  shopper s
    LEFT JOIN  orders o ON o.id_shopper = s.id_shopper
    LEFT JOIN  country c ON c.id_country = s.id_country
    LEFT JOIN  region r ON r.id_region = s.id_region
    LEFT JOIN  city ct ON ct.id_city = s.id_city
    LEFT JOIN  area a ON a.id_area = s.id_area
    GROUP BY  s.id_shopper, s.upi, s.email, s.first_name, s.last_name1,
        s.last_name2, s.shtype, s.active, s.registered_on, s.upi_type,
        s.phtype1, s.phacode1, s.phone1, s.phtype2, s.phacode2,
        s.phone2, s.mail_offers;
```

Explain is the same for both:

```
    mysql> explain SELECT s.id_shopper,(SELECT count(*)FROM shopper s2 JOIN orders o2 ON o2.id_shopper = s2.id_shopper AND o2.order_status in ('V','X') WHERE o2.id_shopper = s.id_shopper)as num_ordenes, s.upi, s.email, s.first_name, s.last_name1, s.last_name2, s.shtype, s.active, s.shtype, s.registered_on AS regdate, s.upi_type AS upi_type, s.gender, s.birthday, s.phtype1, s.phacode1, s.phone1, s.phtype2, s.phacode2, s.phone2, s.sellercode, s.mail_offers, c.name as pais, r.name as region, ct.name as ciudad, a.name as area, s.postcode, s.street, s.street_number, concat(r.name," - ", a.name) as comuna_compra FROM shopper s LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.id_shopper = s.id_shopper LEFT JOIN country c ON c.id_country = s.id_country LEFT JOIN region r ON r.id_region = s.id_region LEFT JOIN city ct ON ct.id_city = s.id_city LEFT JOIN area a ON a.id_area = s.id_area GROUP BY s.id_shopper, s.upi, s.email, s.first_name, s.last_name1, s.last_name2, s.shtype, s.active, s.registered_on, s.upi_type, s.phtype1, s.phacode1, s.phone1, s.phtype2, s.phacode2, s.phone2, s.mail_offers;
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref                   | rows | Extra                           |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | s     | ALL    | NULL            | NULL            | NULL    | NULL                  | 3548 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | o     | ref    | orders_FKIndex1 | orders_FKIndex1 | 4       | rosen_ar.s.id_shopper |    4 | Using index                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY         | 4       | rosen_ar.s.id_country |    1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | r     | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY         | 4       | rosen_ar.s.id_region  |    1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | ct    | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY         | 4       | rosen_ar.s.id_city    |    1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY         | 4       | rosen_ar.s.id_area    |    1 |                                 |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | s2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY         | 4       | func                  |    1 | Using index                     |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | o2    | ref    | orders_FKIndex1 | orders_FKIndex1 | 4       | func                  |    4 | Using where                     |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Indexes from shopper and orders:

```
mysql> show indexes from shopper;
+---------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| shopper |          0 | PRIMARY          |            1 | id_shopper  | A         |        3812 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| shopper |          1 | shopper_FKIndex1 |            1 | id_area     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| shopper |          1 | shopper_FKIndex2 |            1 | id_country  | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| shopper |          1 | shopper_FKIndex3 |            1 | id_city     | A         |         190 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| shopper |          1 | shopper_tbfk_1   |            1 | id_ticket   | A         |          40 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+---------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

mysql> show indexes from orders;
+--------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name           | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| orders |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id_order    | A         |       41181 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| orders |          1 | orders_FKIndex1    |            1 | id_shopper  | A         |         496 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| orders |          1 | orders_FKIndex2    |            1 | ep_id_area  | A         |         840 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| orders |          1 | fk_orders_tiendas1 |            1 | id_tienda   | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+--------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

What could be wrong? Is it because the indexes are set to 1 for very relationship, making it slow? Should I delete the indexes and create them again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I meant it's the same version of mysql, same database, almost the same data (mysqldump from prod to qa), etc..

Answer (score 2):

*I realise this is an old question, but as it is still here, I thought I would address some of the issues that to me seem to be on the surface.*

I do not really have a good explanation why your query runs fine in one environment but not the other.  I do see some issues with it that I believe might cause it to run slow.

First of all, this join seems completely redundant:

```
    LEFT JOIN  orders o ON o.id_shopper = s.id_shopper
```

Nothing is selected from `order`, nor does this table participate in other joins.  The only effect it probably causes is duplication of `shopper` rows, because there are likely multiple orders per shopper.

At the same time, the purpose of the `GROUP BY` appears to be the opposite: de-duplication of the results brought on by the aforementioned join.  Without the join, it is not needed either.  Therefore, remove the `GROUP BY` clause as well.

Finally, the correlated subquery in the `SELECT` clause can be simplified to this:

```
      ( SELECT  count(*)
            FROM  orders o
           WHERE  o.id_shopper = s.id_shopper
             AND  o.order_status in ('V','X')
      )
```

You do not need to have an extra instance of `shopper` there.  It is enough to select directly from `orders`, correlating it with `shopper` from the outer `SELECT`, as shown above.

After applying those changes, the full query would look like this:

```
SELECT  s.id_shopper, 
      ( SELECT  count(*)
            FROM  orders o
           WHERE  o.id_shopper = s.id_shopper
             AND  o.order_status in ('V','X')
      )as num_ordenes, s.upi,
        s.email, s.first_name, s.last_name1, s.last_name2, s.shtype,
        s.active, s.shtype, s.registered_on AS regdate, s.upi_type AS upi_type,
        s.gender, s.birthday, s.phtype1, s.phacode1, s.phone1,
        s.phtype2, s.phacode2, s.phone2, s.sellercode, s.mail_offers,
        c.name as pais, r.name as region, ct.name as ciudad, a.name as area,
        s.postcode, s.street, s.street_number,
        concat(r.name, " - ", a.name) as comuna_compra
    FROM  shopper s
    LEFT JOIN  country c ON c.id_country = s.id_country
    LEFT JOIN  region r ON r.id_region = s.id_region
    LEFT JOIN  city ct ON ct.id_city = s.id_city
    LEFT JOIN  area a ON a.id_area = s.id_area;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Let me explain a problem with the query...**

One `shopper` maps to many `orders`.  From there you get to `c.name as pais, r.name as region, ct.name as ciudad, a.name as area`.  But that means there could be multiple *different* country, city, etc.

This has two problems:

- It means that the `ciudad` displayed will be some value picked at random.
- The `JOIN` explodes the number of rows being looked at, only to have the `GROUP BY` shrink back down.

I recommend you rethink the requirement of having city, etc, in the resultset.  If you remove those columns, and the `LEFT JOINs`, much of the problem will vanish.

If you need to have city, etc, then rethink what value you will use.

In a related thought...  Consider having a `Location` table which contains those 4 columns, and join to that one table instead of running around to 4 tables.

**Back to your question...**

- are tables in both environments using InnoDB?
- are the cache sizes the same (`innodb_buffer_pool_size`)
- is the cache "hot" in both cases?  I suspect it is "cold" in QA -- this can easily lead to it being 10 times as slow.  (OK, 50x is stretching this answer.)